# athena insert and hive format error for HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat

Tags: hive, sql-insert, parquet, amazon-athena

Before the question/issue, here's the setup:

**Table 1**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table1`(
  `mac_address` string, 
  `node` string, 
  `wave_found` string, 
  `wave_data` string, 
  `calc_dt` string, 
  `load_dt` string)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `site_id` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://foobucket/object-thing'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'has_encrypted_data'='false', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1654609315')
```

**Table 2**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table2`(
  `mac_address` string, 
  `node` string, 
  `wave_found` string, 
  `wave_data` string, 
  `calc_dt` string, 
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `load_dt` string, 
  `site_id` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://foobucket/object-thing'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'has_encrypted_data'='false', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1654147830')
```

When the following Athena SQL is executed, the error below is thrown:

```
insert into tabl2
select * from table1;
```

> "HIVE_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT: Output format
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat with SerDe
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe is not
> supported."

That error seems relatively straighforward, but I'm still stuck on
building a solution despite looking for alternatives to the so-called
`HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat`. There's also the partition difference
going on, but I'm not sure if that has any bearing on this current error
shown here.

Here's some sources I've found and used so far: [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/insert-into.html), [2](https://github.com/apache/hive/tree/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/io)